# Styling is not applied to styled component using style(StyledComponent) syntax

Tags: styled-components

Styling a div using `style.div` works just fine.

But styling a styled component using `style(FlexItem)` does nothing.

What might be the reason?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import OuterSectionContainer from './../../ui/OuterSectionContainer';
import InnerSectionContainer from './../../ui/OuterSectionContainer/InnerSectionContainer';
import FlexContainer from './../../ui/OuterSectionContainer/InnerSectionContainer/FlexContainer';
import FlexItem from './../../ui/OuterSectionContainer/InnerSectionContainer/FlexContainer/FlexItem';
import ScaledImage from './../../ui/ScaledImage';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Testamonials = () => {
    const FlexItemStyled = styled(FlexItem)`
        padding: 10px; 
        background-color: red;
        display: none;
    `;

    return (
        <OuterSectionContainer>
            <InnerSectionContainer>
                <FlexContainer>
                    <FlexItemStyled>
                        <ScaledImage src={require('../../../images/logo.png')} />
                    </FlexItemStyled>
                    <FlexItemStyled>
                        <ScaledImage src={require('../../../images/logo.png')} />
                    </FlexItemStyled>
                    <FlexItemStyled>
                        <ScaledImage src={require('../../../images/logo.png')} />
                    </FlexItemStyled>
                    <FlexItemStyled>
                        <ScaledImage src={require('../../../images/logo.png')} />
                    </FlexItemStyled>
                </FlexContainer>
            </InnerSectionContainer>
        </OuterSectionContainer>
    );
};

export default Testamonials;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlexItem` should not be a styled-components, then you should pass `className` in props to use `styled(FlexItem)` syntax.

more info here : https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components